# How to check if a drop down value that is selected matches database value then only the submit button is activated. ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dropdown

I want to check if a drop down value from a drop down list that the user selects matches the database value then only I want to activate a submit button at the end of a form. Please Help. I do not know what I'm supposed to type into this section of the code to make that possible. I already have the database

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=facultylog;Integrated Security=True";
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand("Select Username,Password from Log", con);

        SqlDataReader r = c.ExecuteReader();
        while (r.Read())
        {
    **if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue** 
   ????
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { Response.Write("no"); }
    finally { con.Close(); }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Why not just only populate the dropdown with values that you know exist? Then you won't have to check. It's not really clear what your situation is or how this requirement arose, but it sounds like it's probably avoidable.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you but I was able to fix it. :)